# Remove Blank Rows from an Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I've done some searching but I can't seem to find a quick method to get rid of all BLANK rows within a worksheet. I don't want it to take up much time. Is there such a way?

I've tried a few methods that aren't brilliant that involve filtering blanks in all columns then deleting what's on screen. Maybe there's a function in excel that I'm missing here?

I'm looking for something like the `UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates()` function that did a lot of work in a second or two.

Comment: Are you looking for C# or VBA?  Reason i ask is the example you provide is a VBA function?

Answer (score 2):

Here's two methods to delete all blank rows on the active sheet...

**1 VBA**. This way should be much quicker than looping through rows:

```
cells.RowDifferences(cells(rows.Count,columns.Count)).rows.Hidden=true
cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
cells.Rows.Hidden=false
```

**2 Keyboard**. This way is just three steps in the undo list, so can easily be undone / retraced.

[image]

*Step 1. Select data cells.*
Click left corner heading to select all cells then press `Shift+Tab` `Ctrl+\`

*Step 2. Hide and delete remaining rows.*
Press `Ctrl + 9` `Ctrl + A` `Alt+;` `Ctrl + -`

*Step 3. Unhide selected rows and select first cell.* Press: `Ctrl + Shift + 9` `Ctrl + Home`

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: That's what I was about to recommend (VBA way) though I would have used `xlCellTypeBlank` and then `.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur the method you suggest works well if the blanks are the same in all the columns but not if you have blanks in different columns - in the case above that would delete all the rows. I haven't checked but I imagine similar methods are available in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you need for your functions to work fast in excel you should set global Excel application variables, such as "Visible = false", "ScreenUpdating = false". Filtering the blanks and deleting them should be the fastest approach, although I would go with manually making the list of the rows to delete and then deleting them in one call

```
RowsToDelete = "2:2;4:4;8:8";
Range = Sheet.Range()
Range.Delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

For very large datasets (100k+ rows) I've always found it **massively** quicker to sort by blanks then remove than to filter and remove lots of separated lines.
If the blank rows are spread out throughout the file it can be between 5 and 10 times quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through each row takes forever, but that's only because of the FOR loop overhead.  The main operations WorksheetFunction.CountA and Range.EntireRow.Delete really do not take very long.

The best solution I've found is to start with chunks of 100K rows and delete all that have no values, then move down in powers of 10 until you're at the single row level.

This is fast whether you are trying to remove excess whitespace around your data or removing single rows sporatically within your main data range.

```
Public Sub removeblankrows()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

With WorksheetFunction
    Dim pow As Long

    For pow = 6 To 0 Step -1

        Dim chunkSize As Long: chunkSize = 10 ^ pow

        Dim chunks As Long: chunks = (ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count \ chunkSize) + 1

        Dim c As Long
        For c = chunks To 1 Step -1
            Dim last As Long, first As Long

            last = .Min(c * chunkSize, ws.Rows.Count)
            first = .Max(1, (c - 1) * chunkSize)

            Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range, rng As Range
            Set c1 = ws.Cells(first, 1)
            Set c2 = ws.Cells(last, ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count)

            Set rng = ws.Range(c1, c2)

            If .CountA(rng) = 0 Then rng.EntireRow.Delete

        Next c

    Next pow
End With
```

End Sub